# How to copy automatically my files to another location after a commit using Tortoise SVN?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I am using `Windows7` with `Tortoise SVN`.

I have a folder which is pointing to a path under Subversion (`http://svn.belux.conseur.org/svn/repository/blabla/...`).

I would like to have a script or a way to copy automatically all files from a source folder to a target location on my local network, after committing files.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn export` can do this but you would have to use the command line tool and a batch script.

```
@echo off
svn commit %*
svn export %* \\server\folder\
```